# Auto-launch a program on USB key insertion

Tags: linux, windows, macos, shell, usb

I am looking for a way to store a script on a USB flash drive that will be executed she the device is inserted in a computer.

It should be a script that keep the files on my USB key up to date with their source on the web.

I have identified two main issues :

- Security issue
- Platform agnostic issue: may be easily solved by a test of the platform

Can anyone give me a hint for my research?

Thanks

Comment: I think recent Windows versions disabled this because of security concerns. It is too easy to spread malware via USB using these mechanisms.

Comment: O.O a script which downloads arbitrary files from the internet without the interaction of the user?

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible on the newer versions on windows. But you could try something like a bad usb, it's a usb that you can program to act like a keyboard, try looking it up and see if it is something you can use. If you think it can be used you can create it your self or buy one, if you choose to buy i would recommend either a rubber ducky or a malduino.

Hope it helps ;)